# How to use rx java's interval for background task

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

According to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/257#issuecomment-164263215 . interval is just for active code, and if app is not wake up, it will not work. So how to use interval for background scheduling tasks?

Comment: Do you have any specific use case in mind? What kind of task? How often? What kind of app?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK for example, fetch weather data every 1 hour.

Answer (score 3):

Please DO NOT use this solution:

To use `interval` from `RxJava` you'll have to make sure your app's process stays alive. One way to do it is to put use the `Observable` in a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). This is a bad idea because the service is [NOT actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Waiting for time to pass is not delivering value for the user. Again please DO NOT use this.

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [JobScheduler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) (or it's backport [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager)) are far better choices for repeating background activities. If you use `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` the system can batch jobs from multiple apps together to save battery. Using `JobScheduler` enables you to execute your background jobs in specific conditions, eg. when the device is connected to the internet or when battery is more than 20%. (Internet is required to check the weather).

`interval` from `RxJava` does have it's usage on Android. It's an excellent replacement for `Runnable.postDelayed` for relatively short durations. It makes the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: Can I create a publishsubject, subscribe it on Application create, and every time when a AlarmManager triggered a BroadcastReceiver, call onNext on publishsubject?

Comment: @cgcgbcbc if your app is not in the foreground Android can kill it. Again for your example, fetch weather data every hour `JobScheduler` is the most efficient approach. https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule a task that should be run even if app is not active anymore then use `AlarmManager`.

If you need to schedule a task that should be run only when app is active then you can use `Observable.interval()` and react on emission to execute some code and please don't forget to unsubscribe from the `Observable` when appropriate (when `Activity` is paused, etc) so app won't burn the battery!

Comment: Can I create a publishsubject, subscribe it on Application create, and every time when a AlarmManager triggered a BroadcastReceiver, call onNext on publishsubject? Would this burn the battery?