# RxJava interval and timeout occasionally stop when Android device is locked

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

One of my apps features is designed to timeout after 5 minutes (to prevent the user from accidentally leaving it enabled).

The Activity displays a countdown timer that is updated by `Observable.interval()` and the feature timeout is implemented via `Observable.timeout()`.

Occasionally when the countdown is running and a user locks the device,  `interval()` will stop emitting and `timeout()` will not throw it's timeout exception. When the device is unlocked and the Activity is again in the foreground, eventually  `timeout` will emit it's exception after an indeterminate amount of time.

It was suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252772/how-to-use-rx-javas-interval-for-background-task/34272022) that `interval` is only for "active code", so I assume this is the issue I am encountering.

Are there simple solutions that would allow me to continue using RxJava for this timeout and countdown, or must I look to other solutions such as `AlarmManager`?  Any special `Scheduler` to the rescue?

Comment: Regarding the last question, check the [Job scheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html). You have to show some code for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

> It was suggested in this SO post that interval is only for "active
>   code", so I assume this is the issue I am encountering.

That is correct. All 'timed' methods (`interval`, `delay`, `timeout`) of RxJava will fail drastically once the phone is locked and power saving features start kicking in (light and deep doze). While hunting down a similar bug I could not find exactly what was going on, but overall intervals of seconds can turn out to only be triggered after minutes, and intervals of minutes hours.

If I have to venture a guess, I would expect this to be related to [RxJava's logic only executing within specific maintenance windows](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) while the screen is off.

> Are there simple solutions that would allow me to continue using
>   RxJava for this timeout and countdown, or must I look to other
>   solutions such as AlarmManager?

In your specific case, it depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to close down/notify the user after a *precise* time? An `AlarmManager` as you suggest is likely the way to go (`JobScheduler` is to loosely schedule jobs that run in batches with jobs scheduled by other applications). In case you want to show a timer while the app is active, you could do so by storing the start time when the application starts, and then using a `Observable.interval` to update the interface at a regular interval (performing the current time - start time calculation). You likely would want to unsubscribe from this interval when the screen is turned off.

Lastly, very simple, but unlikely what you need, you can use [a wake lock to keep the phone awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock). The `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler` acquire and release a wake lock for you.

P.s. Consider that using exception logic (RxJava's `timeout`) to handle normal application logic might not be a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
```

But you need to make sure that you correctly unsubscribe, and not clone multiple observables.

Comment: Doesnt make sense. That means that he creates a new Thread which timeouts aswell. The only solution is to use a wakelock or as he already said an alarmmanager due security policy..